# Websocket replacement?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, web

I'm working on a project where a page, needs to be able to keep updated according to the state of a server.

I like websockets for this since they offer me a way of pushing messages from the server, but availability is a problem.

I need generic way to do two way communication between a webserver and a browser-client.

I would like to be able to hold a large amount of clients on my server, so busywaiting clients is not a good solution.

I've looked at long pooling, but this seames like busy waiting on the clients part -- is it the only way to go if I need IE support?

This question is only about the clients end of the transactions.

Comment: What are you prepared to use on the server side?

Comment: @Tomalak: I'm planing on using [mochiweb](https://github.com/mochi/mochiweb) serverside.

Comment: Seems like a good choice to handle many concurrently open requests. Subjectively I'd say long polling is not a bad option on the client side if you want down-level compatibility.

Comment: @Tomalak: I think you are right. But What I would like to have is alot of pasive connections hanging.. and the constant setting up, and breaking down of connections could perhaps, someday be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need two-way communication? If not you should use [SSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events) (Server-sent Events). They are also easier to simulate in IE (as SSE actually degrades gracefully to long-polling on older systems).

Comment: That is really interesting.. but the IE issue anois me.. perhaps I can find someone whom has made a IE equivalent..

Comment: There is no equivalent (especially when you need to support IE6) because IE6 doesn't support long running (streaming) responses very well. So on IE you are gonna be stuck with some thing like long-polling (at best). SSE supports sending a last-event-id header to the server in order to pickup any events since the last seen (on the client side) event. So SSE is actually just long-polling with some optimisations (for modern browsers)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct there is a problem with longpolling, it tends to consume loads of resources.

What you need is as i can see  solution that has a fallback to HTTP longopolling for elder not Websockets API speaking browsers.  SSE is a alternvative,but Websockets feels as a more convinent

If you are running on the .NET plattform XSockets.NET can be a alternative, it supports Websockets (RFC6544 and Hybi00) and fallbacks on HTTP Longpolling when needed (i.e IE )

Have a look at http://xsockets.net

Comment: I'm not using the .NET platform -- and it sounds alot like SSE

Answer (score 0):

Have you reviewed http://signalr.net/ ? Based on websockets but will gracefully downgrade to the nearest available component to support a socket type connection.

Docs can be found here: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki

Comment: Under the about and learn sections? Also more info can be found on their GitHub page. https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR#readme